# Mark message as read after action taken from email

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, email

At the bottom of the "So and so viewed your Stack Overflow Careers profile and sent you a message" email, I clicked the "Not interested" link:

[image: Not interested]

That link takes me to careers.stackexchange.com, where I see this:

[image: 1 messages]

"Ooh, a new message!" I say excitedly. So I click it and am disappointed that it is the message that I just read in my email.

Please mark that message as read after I action it from my email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds reasonable! I have just pushed this change, so from now on hitting the Interested or Not Interested button will also mark the original message as read in your Careers inbox.

Comment: That was fast! 